# Reverse Proxy Public Private Url with Parameter

Tags: apache-http-server, url, reverse-proxy, parameters

I am trying to setup a reverse proxy with redhat machines running Apache 2.2.15, where the public and private URL contains parameters (static, same for all requests coming through the public url), so the setup should work like this:

User -> public.url:8080/appName/jsoncall?call=SaveOrUpdateSyncObject 
     ->private.url:8080/appName/jsoncall?call=SaveOrUpdateSyncObject

there more than one url and all are predefine url

I have managed to setup the reverse proxy using the following directives in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.

however I am not sure how to accomplish the addition of the ?parameter=value suffix to the public and private url

Comment: You probably want some [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) rules.

Comment: yes, but i didn't set port and query string in public url and there are multiple query string url only change parameter value kindly help me out how can i set rewrite rule in multiple such type of url. @Anaksunaman